# Assign non persisted object to view using extbase

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

While trying to assign an object to a view in my controller action I get the following message because this object is not persisted:

> Could not serialize Domain Object Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Object. It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object.

Is there any possibility to add this object to the view without creating a databaseentry?

Comment: Did you extend the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject for your class?

Comment: I agree Jozef... is your Object a Value Object instead of an Entity?

Comment: Yes I did. It is an emtity object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception `[InvalidArgumentValueException('Could not serialize Domain Object $className. It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object.', 1260881688)][1]` is thrown in the `UriBuilder`, thus when a model shall be used as argument for creating a link.

The instance of `Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Object` must either fulfill these requirements:

- can be represented as array (is array or implements `Iterator` interface) *OR*
- extends `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject` *AND one of*

  - extends `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractValueObject` *OR*
  - having a valid `uid`, not `null`

Thus, if you instantiated the object directly in the controller, the `uid` property is not defined yet. This property is assigned if domain objects are fetched or added with a repository.

### TypeConverters

TypeConverters allow to convert from a given identifier (some string representation, hash-value, ...) to a proper domain object. The following links show how to do that for the concept of an IBAN (International Bank Account Identifier).

- [IBAN model](https://github.com/TYPO3Incubator/bank_account_example/blob/0.2.2/Classes/Domain/Model/Iban/Iban.php)
- [TypeConverter to create object from string](https://github.com/TYPO3Incubator/bank_account_example/blob/0.2.2/Classes/Domain/Property/TypeConverter/IbanTypeConverter.php)

TypeConverters have to registerd in `ext_localconf.php` like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerTypeConverter(
    \H4ck3r31\BankAccountExample\Domain\Property\TypeConverter\IbanTypeConverter::class
);
```

The `Iban` object can be used then in your controller:

```
public function someAction(Iban $iban) { ... }
```

### Use array representation of your object

Another alternative could be to assign an array representation of the domain object to the view and use that to fill the link arguments:

```
$this->view->assign('myObject', $object->toArray());
```

When invoking a controller action, the object is reconstituted from the submitted array keys and are used as properties - thus array keys and properties must have the same naming, or a persistence column mapping is defined.

```
public function someAction(MyObject $object) { ... }
```

In my previously mentioned bank account example it looks like this:

- [BankDto model](https://github.com/TYPO3Incubator/bank_account_example/blob/0.2.2/Classes/Domain/Model/Bank/BankDto.php#L43)
- [Controller action invocation](https://github.com/TYPO3Incubator/bank_account_example/blob/0.2.2/Classes/Controller/ManagementController.php#L57)

The term "Dto" is the abbreviation for "Data Transfer Object", thus it's not a real domain entity, does not have a proper UID and is just used to encapsulate information in a domain object when passing that to different components.

Comment: All in all it can be said that there is no visualisation without persisting?

Comment: Better: Linking to entities without having a valid UID is not possible. The UID is assigned when objects get persisted and written to a database table. I'll update the answer to use type-converters or to use arrays directly.